# Test if matrix is sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

In R, is there a way to tell if a matrix is sparse? There are many sparse matrix classes, for example `dgCMatrix`, and there is no `is.sparseMatrix` method.

Comment: Dug out of the "Intro2Matrix" vignette: `is(sM, 'sparseMatrix')`, where `sM` is a sparse matrix.

Comment: Amazing, I wish it had a corresponding is.sparseMatrix call!

Comment: @JCWong - `is.sparseMatrix <- function(x) is(x, 'sparseMatrix')` and away you go ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "spam" package: `as.spam(..)` makes an object of class spam out of your matrix and then apply `summary(..)`, witch gives you the density of your matrix or `display(..)`, for a graphical representation of the non-zero entries

```
testMatrix <-as.spam(matrix(c(123, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 23, 0, 0), nrow = 3))
summary(testMatrix)
display(testMatrix)
```

Answer (score -2):

`aa` is sparse matrix

```
if(length(which(is(aa)=="sparseMatrix"))!=0){
aa=Matrix(aa,sparse=0)
    }
```

'
if `aa` is sparse matrix ,convert `aa` into **non-sparse matrix**